# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

```
No module named 'win32'
```

I'm getting this error can anyone help ?

I am getting this error when trying to run the codes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please give us more information. Why do you expect the module `win32` to be there?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have chosen the correct python interpreter.

Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose your python interpreter where you stored the python module.